# c# asp net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp

Buenas , tengo un controlador con las operaciones para editar un registro, algo como esto:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string weblogin, byte tienda)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Clientes clientes = db.Clientes.First(x => x.id);

        if (clientes == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(clientes);
    }

    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,nombre,apellido1,apellido2,....")] Clientes clientes)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(clientes).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(clientes);
    }
```

Si lo invoco desde el `controlador/Edit/parametros` me carga el formulario correspondiente para editar los datos y me deja 
guardar los datos que invoca al segundo `action result`

Ahora intento poner esto de un formulario que contiene unos `tabs` el código es este:

```
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Clientes", new
            {
                id = Model.clientes.id,
                tienda = Model.clientes.tienda,
            });
        }
    </div>
```

El error que me da es este:

> [InvalidOperationException: No se permiten acciones 
>       secundarias para ejecutar acciones de redireccionamiento.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +164

Como debería hacer esto?
Gracias.