# asp net mvc5 : No se permiten acciones secundarias para ejecutar acciones de redireccionamiento

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando con mvc5 y EF

Tengo un controlador con las operaciones para editar un registro algo como esto

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, string weblogin, byte tienda)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Clientes clientes = db.Clientes.First(x => x.id == id && x.weblogin == weblogin && x.tienda == tienda);

        if (clientes == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(clientes);
    }

    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,nombre,apellido1,apellido2,....")] Clientes clientes)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(clientes).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(clientes);
    }
```

Si lo invoco desde el controlador/Edit/parametros me carga el formulario correspondiente para editar los datos y me deja 
guardar los datos que invoca al segundo action result

Ahora intento poner esto de un formulario que contiene unos tabs el código es este

```
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Clientes", new
            {
                weblogin = Model.clientes.weblogin,
                id = Model.clientes.id,
                tienda = Model.clientes.tienda,
            });
        }
    </div>
```

El error que me da es este

`[InvalidOperationException: No se permiten acciones secundarias para ejecutar acciones de redireccionamiento.]
   System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +164`

Gracias,

Se me olvidó comentar que este código lo tengo en un tab y quiero que se cargue al entrar en el

```html
@model testweb.Classes.claseClientesVentas
 

<div>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Datos cliente</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" aria-controls="second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Editar cliente</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#third" aria-controls="third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Ventas</a></li>

    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="first">
            
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("Details", "Clientes", new { weblogin = Model.clientes.weblogin,
                                                               id = Model.clientes.id,
                                                               tienda = Model.clientes.tienda,
                                                               tab = true
                                                               
                });
            }
         </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
           @{
               Url.Action("Edit", "Clientes", new
               {
                   weblogin = Model.clientes.weblogin,
                   id = Model.clientes.id,
                   tienda = Model.clientes.tienda,
               });
          }
        </div>



    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="third">
        33 <br />
         
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: en qué se diferencia de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70386/c-asp-net-mvc5 ?

Answer (score 2):

Reemplaza `Html.RenderAction` por `Url.Action`

```
@{
   Url.Action("Edit", "Clientes", new
   {
     weblogin = Model.clientes.weblogin,
     id = Model.clientes.id,
     tienda = Model.clientes.tienda,
   });
}
```

Comment: Gracias , he probado a hacer este cambio pero entonces no me carga "nada" , con el otro código me carga el formulario con su vista pero me da error al guardar. Tengo un breakpoint en el controlador y allí no me entra.

Comment: claro, es un enlace que te va a dirigir a un formulario de edición

Comment: y como podría hacerlo se te ocurre alguna manera? Gracias

Comment: una posible solución: Click en editar (enlace o botón) y que aparezca un modal con un formulario de edición :D

Answer (score 0):

has probado a decorar tu método del controlador con `[ChildActionOnly]`? Puedes ver más información en [Clase ChildActionOnlyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string weblogin, byte tienda)
{
    if (id <= 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Clientes clientes = db.Clientes.First(x => x.id == id && x.weblogin == weblogin && x.tienda == tienda);

    if (clientes == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(clientes);
}
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta , pero me da el mismo problema

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: No se permiten acciones secundarias para ejecutar acciones de redireccionamiento.]
   System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +164